# regex to match the last line with a number or word before empty line

Tags: java, regex

I have a plain text table as follows:

```
A lot of text and various tables which can all be different

SI Table - Total 
 Total

Heartburn  0.0
Regurg 14.3
ChestP 25.0
Cough n/a
Belch n/a
Other n/a
Vomiting n/a

some other stuff which can include 443.66 or 332 numbers
```

but this can also be

```
SI Table - Total 
     Total
Cough n/a
Heartburn  0.0
Regurg 14.3
Chest Pain 25.0
Belch n/a
Other n/a
CHest Pain 0.34
```

The expected output from sample 1 would therefore be

```
SI Table - Total 
     Total

Heartburn  0.0
Regurg 14.3
ChestP 25.0
Cough n/a
Belch n/a
Other n/a
Vomiting n/a
```

I want to extract as a single string from SI Table to the value of the last symptom in the same table.

The only pattern is the last symptom and value is always followed by an empty line but there can be anything after that- including a very similar table. I tried

```
 Pattern SAPDay2_pattern = Pattern.compile("SAP Table - Day1 .*(\\d+\\.\\d+|n\\/a)\\n\\n",Pattern.DOTALL);
```

but it doesn't work. Can somebody help?

Comment: What is `SAP Table - Day1`? You should show more complete input sample with multiple tables. Also include your expected matches.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this regex:

```
SI Table *- *Total\s+Total\s*(?:\n[A-Za-z]+\s+(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?|n/a))+
```

[RegEx Demo](http://regexr.com/3dhk1)